# Detect Ctrl + click in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to replace detecting a double-click with detecting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click, but I do not know how to do so.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).dblclick(function (e) {
        var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
        var tag = target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (!(tag == 'input' || tag == 'textarea' || tag == 'img')) {       
            openIfSelected("dblclick");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this really for a Google Chrome Extension (it looks like a generic jQuery question)? If so, why are you using `(event && event.srcElement)` when you do not appear to define `event`. Even if you meant `(e && e.srcElement)`, `event.srcElement` is a old IE thing (ignoring that you are using jQuery). If this is a Google Chrome extension, there is no need to have code which exists to deal with old browsers. You might need things to deal with other browsers if you are trying to have your extension work in multiple browsers which are/are becoming compatible with Chrome extensions, but not IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the jQuery [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method and the [`MouseEvent.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey) property.

You could do something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey){
            var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (!(tag == 'input' || tag == 'textarea' || tag == 'img')) {       
                openIfSelected("dblclick"); //Still pass "dblclick", but upon Ctrl-click
            }
        }
    });
});

function openIfSelected(reason){
    //This is now only called upon Ctrl-click, but the "reason" remains "dblclick".
    console.log('Called "openIfSelected" with reason: ' + reason);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click me</div>
```

**Note:**
You used the code:

```
var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
```

This is strange as written. You were probably attempting to use `window.event`. However, this is not needed because you are using [jQuery, which normalizes the event object that is passed to event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event), specifically so you don't have to do things like this. In addition, the tags you are using declare this question as a Google Chrome extension issue. If that is the case, and you weren't using jQuery, then you would still not need to do this as you do not need to account for the use of the code in older browsers (e.g. IE).

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, it helped me like when I use 'ctrl', 'ctrl' is activate. But word does not selected.

Yes you right it is jQuery code. I try to edit this code in 'content_script.js' file.

Actually I added dictionary extension to my Google Chrome Browser, then I decided I'd add 'Ctrl' when I select any word with 'double click'. That mean I tryin when I 'Ctrl + Double Click' word could open new tab...

Please help me.

Comment: I tryied like below.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey){
            var target = e.target;
            var tag = target.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (!(tag == 'input' || tag == 'textarea' || tag == 'img')) {
                openIfSelected("dblclick");
            }
        }
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

I fixed like this. Big thanks Makyen.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if(event.ctrlKey){
            var target = event.srcElement;
            var tag = target.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (!(tag == 'input' || tag == 'textarea' || tag == 'img')) {
                openIfSelected("dblclick");
            }
        }
    });
});
```